Haar integral over the unitary subgroup of $O(2n,\mathbb{R})$
Its well known that the standard $n$ dimensional complex unitary group is a subgroup of the $2n$ dimensional orthogonal group upon choosing a complex structure (or symplectic form). The phrase used for this is the "two-out-of-three property". Call this subgroup $\tilde{\mathrm{U}}(n)\subset \mathrm{O}(2n)$ to distinguish it from the "true" unitary group which consists of $n$ dimensional complex matrices.
I am interested in the integral
\begin{align}
    \int_{\tilde{\mathrm{U}}(N)}d\mu(U) U,
\end{align}
where $\mu$ is the Haar measure on the unitary group and the integration variable is a $2n\times 2n$ dimensional orthogonal matrix which happens to live in this specific subgroup we've identified with the unitary group.
I expect there is some way to deal with such an integral, for example using Schur's lemma, but I am not well versed in this topic so I'd appreciate any help!
Its relatively easy to convince yourself that this matrix is symmetric, commutes with the relevant symplectic form and idempotent (so its some sort of projector), its also invariant under multiplication by any element of $\tilde{\mathrm{U}}(n)$.
